# how to manually install the locally compiled python library (shared python library) to system?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation, environment-variables

I have the newest version of python (2.7.11) installed on my home director. To compile the YouCompleteMe plugin, I need the python-dev to be installed. However, the global python of my environment is 2.7.11, which means that if I install python-dev via apt-get, it would incompatible with python 2.7.11, because it is used for python 2.6.

I re-compiled python 2.7.11 with `--enable-shared` flag, but failed to know how to add its lib and header files to system's default search path (if there exist such a path environment variable).

So, my question is, how to manually install the locally compiled python library to system?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the 2.7 version : apt-get install python2.7-dev

Comment: Does it support all sub-version of 2.7? For example, 2.7.11 and 2.7.9?